# How do I make a skewed tree using fork() in C?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, system

I am looking to create a skewed tree with 3 nodes, 2 of which will have 1 child and the last node will be childless. I do not really understand how to proceed with this.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMkeV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the normal use of `fork()`, basically. Here's some pseudocode:

```
// start in process 3
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
   int pid2 = fork();
   if (pid2 == 0) {
       // process 1
   } else {
       // process 2
   }
} else {
   // process 3
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand how you ended up with 3 processes after 2 forks. My professor told me that it always creates 2^n number of processes. Or is that only if you fork right after another fork? If I understand correctly after reading up on it, by forking in the if statement, only pid2 performs the fork(), is this correct?

Comment: You started with one process. After the first fork you have two. One of them just continues (`//process 3`) and the other calls `fork()` again, so then you have three. Your understanding is correct.